# WordPress REST API validation always considers arrays to be empty

Tags: wordpress, rest

```
    'methods' => ['POST', 'GET'],
    'args' =>
    [
        'users' =>
        [
            'type' => 'array',
            'minItems' => 1,
            'items' =>
            [
                'type' => 'object',
                'properties' =>
                [
                    'user_login' =>
                    [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'required' => true,
                        'validate_callback' => function($user_login)
                        {
                            error_log("login validation");
                        }
                    ],
                    'user_email' =>
                    [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'required' => false,
                        'validate_callback' => function($user_email)
                        {
                            error_log("email validation");
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'callback' => function($request)
    {
        return $request->get_body_params();
    }
]
```

As is, every request fails, saying that the `users` array is empty. ~~If I comment out the```minItems` line, the request succeeds and I can get the parameters in the callback; however, neither error log fires, so I can't validate the incoming data. I suspect that the main issue is whatever is causing the minItems to fail, as the API for some reason thinks there's no data, and thus nothing to validate, until the main callback fires.~~

Edit: minItems now works. The problem is otherwise the same: the args are treated as empty until the main callback fires, at which point they're populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Validation callbacks can only be added to top-level args, not items of arrays or properties of objects. I'm going to make a feature request; I'll try to remember to update this post if it gets approved.